# Apply class by name to CSS elements with selector without JS

Tags: css, class, selector

Is it possible to apply the class with CSS to subelement as in the following example, without adding `<el class="classname">` to each element?

HTML

```
<div id="container">
   <p>TEXT</p>
   <div>text</div>

   <p>TEXT</p>
   <div>text</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
   background-color:#000;
   color:#FFF;
}
#container > p {
   color:#F0F0F0;
   /* APPLY ALSO CLASS TITLE TO ALL #container > p */
}
#container > div {
   font-size:125%;
   /* APPLY ALSO CLASS WRITE TO ALL #container > div */
}

.titles {
     font-family:....;
     font-style:....;
     /* and so on */
}
.write {
     /* some stuff */
}
```

Comment: Nope. CSS can't assign classes to elements. Best you can do is `#container > div, .write { ..... }`

Comment: No. I believe what youre looking for is similar to @mixin with SASS, which isnt available in CSS.

Comment: Thank you, but what if I change something in the class `.titles`? Then I have to change that in 20 places instead of 1... Ok for JQuery, if everybody has JS enabled

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. There is no way in CSS to say that you want `#container > p` to also include all the styles you've written for `.titles`.

However, take a look at [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/). Writing Sass is a lot like writing CSS, but it lets you do exactly what you've described here. You could write:

```
.titles { 
    ...
}
#container > p {
    @extend .titles;
    ...
}
```

This is ***not*** something the browser knows how to do, but the browser never sees it. Sass turns your special code into real CSS, and you use that on your site.

Using pure CSS, you'd have to do something like:

```
.titles, #container > p, #container >div {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't apply classes to elements from within CSS.  What you would do is copy the code from the `.tiles` & `.write` classes and apply it to the the elements you want styled that way.

Something that can make this relationship easier to manage is a CSS pre-processor like `Less` or `Sass`

Answer (score 0):

This would work but it's not very elegant. Unfortunately all the styles would be used on the parent element which would cause problems most of the time. What you need is SASS or LESS like already mentioned so you can create reusable functions that allow flexibilty.

```
.titles,
.titles > p {
     font-family:....;
     font-style:....;
     /* and so on */
}
.write,
.write > div {
     /* some stuff */
}

div id="container" class="titles write">
   <p>TEXT</p>
   <div>text</div>

   <p>TEXT</p>
   <div>text</div>
</div>
```